# Inner product and canonical forms

Tags: vector-spaces, bilinear-form

If $V$ is a vector space with finite dimension and for some symmetric bilinear form $f: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how to I show that $f$ defines an inner product iff the unique real canonical form of $f$ is $I_n$.

So I know that we can represent the bilinear form as a quadratic form and from sylvesters law of inertia we have that there must be exactly one canonical (Thus proving uniqueness). However, for this how do I start showing that the basis elements are all orthogonal with full rank?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you define a symplectic basis for $V$?

Comment: What is that exactly?

Comment: Look up in :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space where it says "standard symplectic base ". Maybe that will work.

Comment: Dear afggs, I'm not sure why @user99680 is mentioning symplectic bases, but they aren't relevant to your question, which is about a symmetric bilinear form.  ("Symplectic" is about bilinear forms which are *antisymmetric*, rather than symmetric.)  What might be more relevant is the concept of [polarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Symmetric_bilinear_forms), which shows how to pass back and forth between a symmetric bilinear form and the associated quadratic form.  Regards,

Comment: @Matt E. I'm not referring to symplectic forms, but to symplectic _bases_.

Comment: @user99680: Dear user, Fair enough, you have some other notion of symplectic basis in mind, I guess.  (To me, a *symplectic basis* suggests a basis adapted to a symplectic form, chosen so that the symplectic form gets put into a standard shape. Skimming the wikipedia page, I didn't see what the alternative interpretation was that you had in mind; but I probably only saw what I was expecting to see.)  Regards,

Comment: @Matt E: Sorry, I should have been more clear myself. When I have more time, I will try to give a cleare description, or maybe I'll realize I was/am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take any basis $\{{e_i\}}$ of $V$; there should be no problem in constructing one. This enables one to construct the symmetric matrix: $f_{i j}:=f(e_i,e_j)$. Diagonalise $f_{i j}$ using the eigenvalues. If all the eigenvalues are positive, it is an inner product.

Comment: To check symmetry and non-degeneracy, one has to additionally check that $f_{i j}$ is a symmetric, non-singular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

First you construct the matrix $A = (f(e_i,e_j))$ for any given basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ of $V$. By Sylvester's law of inertia, there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $B=S^TAS$ is diagonal with only $-1,0,1$ as eigenvalues.

To be a inner product $f$ must satisfy some properties. We already have that $f$ is symmetric and bilinear, it remains to impose that $f$ is positive definite: $f(x,x) \geq 0$ and $f(x,x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$. This happens if and only if $B$ is positive definite which means that the only possible eigenvalue for $B$ is $1$.

To finish, let $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ be the basis given by $v_j = Se_j$. In this new basis $f$ is the standard inner product.

Another way to see this is to use the spectral theorem on $A$ and then rescale the eigenvalues. You'll actually prove Sylvester's theorem along the way.

Comment: A subtle point about the last statement: the spectral theorem, in the form of diagonalisability of symmetric matrices, does show the existence of o.n.b for any symmetric bilinear form. However, the Sylvester's law of inertia is actually a bit stronger; it also says that given any o.n.b, the set of positive, negative and zero diagonal elements remain the same. This statement does not follow from the spectral theorem.

Comment: Yes, one has to rescale using the square root of the absolute value of each eigenvalue. Only the sign remains unchanged. Moreover, the rescaling is diagonal preserving the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.